# ResourceNotFoundException: The given campaign does not exist AWS Personalize

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

When I'm trying to get recommendations from PersonalizeRuntime got an error : ResourceNotFoundException: The given campaign does not exist: [campaign arn]
But this campaign exists and works on local environment and different EC2 instance with backend wrote on Node.js. Any Ideas what I can missed?

Comment: Are you connecting to the right region? with the right permissions (IAM role)?

Comment: For connection I'm only use an access_key_id and secret_key of user with full access to amazon personalize in such region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to examine all your AWS-related configuration variables. You could be trying to access the campaign from a different region or profile which would make it invisible to your code.